# Блокируется кроссдоменный запрос, laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Помогите плиз. Делаю кроссдоменный  post запрос c vue.cli при помощи axios к бэкенду на laravel 8, в файле cors.php прописал заголовки, методы, но post запросы блокируются 'has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.' но get запросы проходят без проблем, подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема.

```
//vue.cli
  test(){
     axios.post(this.$root.apiUrl+'employees', this.form)
        .then(response=>{
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
       })
  },
//cors.php
return:[ 'paths' => ['api/*'],

'allowed_methods' => ['HEAD', 'PUT', 'POST', 'GET', 'PATH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['Content-Type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With'],


'exposed_headers' => ['x-custom-response-header'],

'max_age' => 60,

'supports_credentials' => false,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Сами роуты к которым вы обращаетесь не должны использовать `Middleware Cors`. Рекомендую создать роуты в файле `route/api.php`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!